# Handling consumer key and secrets for an iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, http, oauth

As a beginner I have a few questions that I would like to ask. I am working on an iOS project which is going to be consuming API's such as Twitter and Instagram. I mainly do this to learn how to work with APIs, learn working with HTTP, learn some libraries like Alamofire etc. and at the same time get more familiar with Swift and UI building in iOS in general.

My specific question is about my consumer keys (in this case from Twitter). Similar questions were asked in a lot of places and I have researched them as well, but I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Obviously, I don't want my client secret and client key to be visible in my code and in my github page. I have read about using environment variables for this, but (although I'm not that experienced in all this) it sounds like the secret is still "shipped" with the app, and could be decompiled in some way.

In short, how should I handle the keys and secrets? If I manage to store it safely somewhere and access it from within my code, will someone still be able to see the key and the secret from the HTTP requests being sent to the key provider (e.g. Twitter in this case)?

Also, a small side question is about the callback URL rules I've seen at Twitter ([here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-twitter-login-error-code-415/107775)), where if you use a URL scheme for your app, they require you to use something like this:

myURLScheme-CONSUMERKEY://

How sensitive is the consumer key compared to the secret? Is it safe to use this in the safari view to redirect a user back to the app? Could it be interrupted/stolen by the users of the app?

I hope the question is clear. All remarks and suggestions are really welcome.